# agregate sales totals per years per customer in one transaction

Tags: mysql

i have a normal turnover table with 3 columns "customer" , "year", "amount"
(for example)

| customer | year | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| anton | 2020 | $5 |
| paul | 2019 | $12 |
| anton | 2021 | $5 |
| paul | 2019 | $10 |
| felicia | 2021 | $5 |
| anton | 2019 | $12 |
| felipe | 2019 | $12 |

and i have the following mysql query

```sql
SELECT `customer` , SUM(`amount`) as summ FROM `customer`.`accountsales` WHERE `amount`> 0 GROUP BY `customer` ORDER BY summ DESC ;
```

This transaction gives me a nice Paretto table with the sales of each customer in descending order

| name | sales all years |
| --- | --- |
| customer1 | sum of all transactions of customer1 |
| customer2 | sum of all transactions of customer2 |
| customer3 | sum of all transactions of customer3 |

so far so good, i want to go one step further and i want to create the following table

| Name | Sales all years | Sales 2021 | Sales2020 | Sales2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer1 | sum1 | sum2021 from customer1 | sum2020 from customer1 | sum2019 from customer1 |
| customer2 | sum2 | sum2021 from customer2 | sum2020 from customer2 | sum2019 from customer2 |
| customer3 | sum3 | sum2021 from customer3 | sum2020 from customer3 | sum2019 from customer3 |

but i want to do it in only one transaction, because the initial table is very huge.

can someone give a hint ?

p.S. feel free to edit the title since I am not very inspired today

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT `customer` , 
       SUM(`amount`) 'Sales all years',
        SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2021 THEN `amount` ELSE 0 END)  Sales2021,
        SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2020 THEN `amount` ELSE 0 END)  Sales2020,
        SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2019 THEN `amount` ELSE 0 END)  Sales2019
FROM accountsales
GROUP BY `customer`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35759f/2/0)**:

```
| customer | Sales all years | Sales2021 | Sales2020 | Sales2019 |
|----------|-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|    anton |              22 |         5 |         5 |        12 |
|  felicia |               5 |         5 |         0 |         0 |
|   felipe |              12 |         0 |         0 |        12 |
|     paul |              22 |         0 |         0 |        22 |
```